# How to add Nodelist/HtmlColection new method by prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Both typeof `document.querySelectorAll('a')` and `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` is **Object**, so I why I can't add a method in this way:

```
        Object.prototype.method = function(){ alert(this); }
```

But, this work:

```
        a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        a.__proto__.__proto__.method = function(){ alert(this); }
        a.method();//object HTMLCollection
```

I thought `a.__proto__ == a.constructor.prototype`, does it?

Comment: This may be useful to you: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('a').constructor.name` returns `'NodeList'`. That means you can assign directly to `NodeList.prototype.method` and it will work as expected (in the decent browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Using Object.prototype is possible. However I do not recommend messing up with it.

*instance_of_my_object = document.getElementsByTagName('a');* is a single instance of your Object. In this case instance_of_my_object is a NodeList.
**instance_of_my_object.method = ...** attaches your method or variable to this single instance of NodeList.

If you want to attach some method to all the instances of a class then you can use prototype (like this : **className.prototype.myMethod = function () ...**).

Answer (score 0):

I found this very useful in my case:

```js
NodeList.prototype.toArray = function() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(this);
};
```

This both shows how to add a method to `NodeList` in this case, and how to turn them to old simple arrays and have the options of an array like `concat`, `foreach`, and so on.
You can do the same for `HTMLCollection`, too. Have fun :)